# prev or siblings select jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<li class="page_item "><a href="javascript:">A</a>
<ul class="children">
    <li class="page_item"><a href="javascript:">1</a></li>
    <li class="page_item"><a href="javascript:">2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="page_item "><a href="javascript:">B</a>
<ul class="children">
    <li class="page_item"><a href="javascript:">1</a></li>
    <li class="page_item"><a href="javascript:">2</a></li>
    <li class="page_item"><a href="javascript:">3</a></li>
    <li class="page_item"><a href="javascript:">4</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

$('.children a').click(function(event){ 
    event.stopPropagation();
        $('ul.children').prev().css('background','red');  
});
```

ONLINE SAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/uybPf/

I'd like to achieve when I click A or B's submenu, and then A or B will be highlighted. but my code highlighted all of them. I don't want to use `toggleClass()`  could someone please help to fix my code. Thanks

Comment: May I recommend this great course to help you better understand jQuery https://tutsplus.com/course/30-days-to-learn-jquery/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're using `ul.children` which will perform the code for **every** element in that set. Try this instead:

```
$('.children a').click(function(event){ 
    event.stopPropagation();
    $("ul.children").prev().css('background','none');
    $(this).closest("ul.children").prev().css('background','red');  
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/uybPf/6/

Comment: As far as I remember, `parents()` goes all the way up the tree and then makes a collection of parents while `closest()` stops at the first match.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl You're right, albeit only 7% difference http://jsperf.com/closest-vs-parents23

Comment: If you are in a huge DOM and in the most-inner element do `parents()` instead of `closest()` I'm sure it will be a significant bigger difference. If in a JsPerf on a tiny DOM example it already is 7% imagine the difference on a more realistic and bigger DOM I'd assume it is exponentially more. Either way +1 as we are talking most likely-never-required performance tuning :)

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Yeah completely agree, I did change that after the performance test. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.children a').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest('ul.children').prev().css('background', 'red');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uybPf/2/

Answer (score 1):

You should use `closest` or `parent` methods:

```
$('.children a').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('.page_item a').removeClass('highlight'); // remove previously active class
    $(this).closest('.children').prev().addClass('highlight');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uybPf/3/

You should better use `addClass` and `removeClass` methods instead of `css` since you already defined `.highlight` class in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.children a').click(function(event){ 
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('>a:first', $(this).closest('.children').closest('.page_item')).css('background', '#f00')
});
```

This however doesn't *unhighlight* the previously highlighted parent

**After reading your question's comments, edit:**

add

```
$('.page_item > a').css('background','transparent');
```

after

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.children a').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest('ul.children').parent().children('a').css('background', 'red');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uybPf/2/